# Foobar Lucky Triple

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Write a function solution(l) that takes a list of positive integers l and counts the number of "lucky triples" of (li, lj, lk) where the list indices meet the requirement i < j < k.  The length of l is between 2 and 2000 inclusive. A "lucky triple" is a tuple (x, y, z) where x divides y and y divides z, such as (1, 2, 4). The elements of l are between 1 and 999999 inclusive.  The solution fits within a signed 32-bit integer. Some of the lists are purposely generated without any access codes to throw off spies, so if no triples are found, return 0.

For example, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] has the triples: [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 6], making the solution 3 total.

My solution only passes the first two tests; I am trying to understand what it is wrong with my approach rather then the actual solution. Below is my function for reference:

```
def my_solution(l):
    from itertools import combinations
    if 2<len(l)<=2000:
        l = list(combinations(l, 3))
        l= [value for value in l if value[1]%value[0]==0 and value[2]%value[1]==0]
        #l= [value for value in l if (value[1]/value[0]).is_integer() and (value[2]/value[1]).is_integer()]
        
        if len(l)<0xffffffff:
            l= len(l)
            return l
        
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: can you specify more what you mean by lucky triples ?

Comment: @mrCopiCat I forgot to add this line. A "lucky triple" is a tuple (x, y, z) where x divides y and y divides z, such as (1, 2, 4).

Comment: Nothing in your code jumps out at me as 'wrong', so I think it's more likely you're running into problems based on time or memory limitations. `combinations()` is a really expensive way to achieve this result, and the fact that you're putting it all into a full `list` instead of just counting the combinations as they come is taking up a lot of space (e.g. do `return sum(1 for v in combinations(l, 3) if v[1] % v[0] == 0 and v[2] % v[1] == 0)` to have the entire thing in a memory-efficient one-liner). There also might be a more efficient way to solve this problem, perhaps using a dict or set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do nested iteration of the full list and remaining list, then compare the two items to check if they are divisors... the result counts as the beginning and middle numbers of a 'triple',

then on the second round it will calculate the third... All you need to do is track which ones pass the divisor test along the way.

For Example

```
def my_solution(l):
    row1, row2 = [[0] * len(l) for i in range(2)]  # Tracks which indices pass modulus
    for i1, first in enumerate(l):  
        for i2 in range(i1+1, len(l)):  # iterate the remaining portion of the list
            middle = l[i2]
            if not middle % first:  # check for matches
                row1[i2] += 1     # increment the index in the tracker lists..
                row2[i1] += 1     # for each matching pair
    result = sum([row1[i] * row2[i] for i in range(len(l))])  
    # the final answer will be the sum of the products for each pair of values.
    return result
```